# Short story about suicide soldiers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I believe the story appeared in Isaac Asimov's sience fiction magazine, but may have been in Fantasy and Science fiction.

Humans are in a war with an unseen, brutal alien race called "shards".

The story is told from the viewpoint of a suicide soldier sent to a planet colony where people refused to evacuate, as the shards butcher people alive and hook their central nervous systems up to their ships' computers/AI.

These suicide soldies have a "glucose pump" which was taken from a captured shard ship.

I would love to know title and author of this piece.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Bright Red Star](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?194679) by Bud Sparhawk ([Asimov's Science Fiction, March 2005](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?88136)) seems a good match.

> **The Shardies don't settle on the planets they take from us. No, they
> just wipe them clean of humanity and then move on.** We knew there had
> to be Shardie gleaners surveying the planet, trying to find some fresh
> meat, or, what was worse, breeding stock. With a little luck, we'd
> find that the Shardies had beaten us to them.
>
> ...
>
> Survivors isn't exactly the word. What they found were sixteen bodies
> without arms, legs, and most organs. **What remained were essentially
> heads hooked up to life support and fueled by oxygenated glucose
> pumps.** There were a couple of hundred strands of glass fiber running
> from the ship's walls into each skull, into each brain, into each
> soul.

Note that [other stories by the same author in the same universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bud_Sparhawk) (such as Glass Box and Cybermarine) also contain similar tropes.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering...it was making me crazy.  Thanks again.